# Big Decimal while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, bigdecimal

I had a while loop which used an integer but I converted it to a big Decimal since the the value was to high and i'm unsure of how to make my while loop work with a big Decimal instead of an integer my code is as  follows.

```
public String getsize()
{
  BigDecimal size = new  BigDecimal(mySize);
  int count = 0;
  String dataType = "";
while (size > 1000 )
  {   
   size = size.divide(size, 1000);
   count++;
  } 
  switch (count)
  {
    case 0:
    dataType = "Bytes";
    break;
    case 1:
    dataType = "KB";
    break;
    case 2:
    dataType = "MB";
    break;
    case 3:
    dataType = "GB";
    break;
    case 4:
    dataType = "KB";
    break;    
  }   
    return size + dataType ;
}
```

The error is at the line while (size > 1000 ) since this is the method if size was an integer. Can someone tell me what the method to do this using a Big Decimal for the size? I've had some trouble coming up with it
EDIT: The solutions given and now an unrelated problem popped up in my division line Im getting: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid rounding mode" any idea of how to fix this? I figured it was better to post here then make an entire new question but if that's whats proper ill do that.

Comment: If you are measuring something in GBs what do you need bigdecimal for?

Comment: To keep the decimal point after the GB I was using a long and got six GB now I get 6.32781826 GB which ill need to round to 6.33 but I needed the lat to decimal points so I could be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare `BigDecimals`, use the [`compareTo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method; `BigDecimal` is `Comparable`.  The `compareTo` method will return an integer greater than 0 if `size` is greater than `thousand`.

```
BigDecimal thousand = new BigDecimal(1000);
while (size.compareTo(thousand) > 0 )
```

Incidentally, it doesn't look like you are doing `BigDecimal` division correctly:

```
size = size.divide(size, 1000);
```

That would interpret `1000` as a [rounding mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int%29) and it would result in an `IllegalArgumentException`.  I think you just need to divide it:

```
size = size.divide(thousand);  // see above for BigDecimal "thousand" declaration
```

Additionally, case 4 is incorrect; it should be "TB" for terabytes after dividing by 1000 4 times (trillions):

```
case 4:
dataType = "TB";
break;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the value you compare against in a `BigDecimal` too and compare them with the `compareTo` method:

```
BigDecimal limit = new BigDecimal("1000");
while (size.compareTo(limit) > 0 ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked and now an unrelated probelm popped up in my divison line Im geting:  "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid rounding mode"  any idea of how to fix this? I figured it was better to post here then make an entire new question

Comment: @AlexChapp You use the wrong method to divide. Because you give `divide` a second int argument [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal,%20int%29) is called. The value 1000 is not a valid value for a rounding mode, so an exception occurs. Use `size = size.divide(limit)` instead.

Comment: @halex is correct.  Please see my answer about why the `IllegalArgumentException` occurs; that method interprets the second argument as a rounding mode, not a divisor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do:

```
BigDecimal compareVal = new BigDecimal(1000);
while(size.compareTo(compareVal) > 0) {
    ...
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

Answer (score 1):

```
compareTo(BigDecimal another)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)

```
BigDecimal k = new BigDecimal("1000");
while(size.compareTo(k)>0)....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
while (size.compareTo(new BigDecimal(1000)) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Even better, define the `1000` value as a local variable:

```
final BigDecimal _1000 = new BigDecimal(1000);
while (size.compareTo(_1000) > 0) {
    // ...
}
```